# Get my documents path in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7

Don't considered this as exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052644/environment-getfolderpathenvironment-specialfolder-internetcache-returns-empty)

I am developing asp.net site in vs 2010. I need to get the **MyDocuments Path** for some storing purpose. So I used the following.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

It works when I run my site in VS. But if I run on IIS(locally), it returns empty value.

So tried to set `AppPoolIdentity to LocalSystem`. But that is also not worked.

How to overcome this situation? Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a strange place to place documents considering your using NetworkServices or LocalSystem for the AppPool. Why not place a path within the web.config file?